# Two cups of coffee is too much / is too many / are too many

Tags: collective-nouns, measure-expressions

My understanding is that depending on whether we consider two cups of coffee as a whole/unit or counting them individually we could say either:

> 1.1 Two cups of coffee is too much (the quantity contained in two cups)
>
> 1.2 Two cups of coffee are too many (1 + 1 = too many cups)
>
> 1.3 *Two cups of coffee is too many (cups)* / Not quite sure but could work as when we say "My favourite food is nuts"

---

If we were to give an answer to "*how many cups a day do you drink?" -"About 5"* I would reply either

> 2.1 That's too much (the quantity)
>
> 2.2 That's too many (cups)

---

And similarly ask these questions

> 3.1 Is two cups a day too much?
>
> 3.2 Are two cups a day too many?
>
> 3.3 *Is two cups a day too many?* / Not quite sure
>
> 3.4 How many cups a day are too many?
>
> 3.5 How many cups a day is too much?

**Are these all correct? Which ones are more natural?**

Comment: Forget the coffee, concentrate on the cups. The coffee is not relevant.

Answer (score 1):

> Two cups of coffee is too much / is too many / are too many

In spoken conversation, sometimes the last word or few words gets left off of the sentence if the speaker believes the listener to be following closely and believes the listener able to "fill in the blanks".

Two cups of coffee is too much *coffee*.

Two cups of coffee is too many *cups* of coffee.  (We say *is* instead of *are* because we mean both cups together as a single group - if the two cups were going to separate people and one person didn't show up, we may say then that "two cups of coffee are too many cups.")

> Are these all correct? Which ones are more natural?

Yep, and you'll probably hear all of these in real-life conversation.

Answer (score 0):

**Much** is used for non-countable quantity and always singular.  **Many** is used for countable quantities and always plural.  It's somewhat confused by the fact that in the US anyway, a "cup" is also a measure of a quantity, so "two cups"  may be taken to mean "about 500 ml" rather than two literal cups.  It makes the intent important.

So,

- Five cups of coffee is too much coffee.
- Two cups of coffee are too many cups of coffee.
- Two cups of coffee is too much coffee.
- Are two cups of coffee too many cups of coffee?
- Is two cups a day too much coffee?

If you add "per day" it becomes a daily quantity and goes to "is."  The number is then thought of as "cups per day" as a single unit.

- Two cups of coffee per day is too many cups per day.

Comment: Thank you. So all my examples were correct included those (2) marked as "not sure"?

Comment: Both labelled "not sure" are also correct, although the first one sounds quite awkward. Maybe only uttered by Starbucks baristas.   A) I made two cups of coffee for that customer.  B) Two cups is too many.  She only wanted one.